# css animation start/stop on scroll

Tags: css, animation, scroll

I've made an sprite sheet animation in css and I want it to run only when the page is scrolled, the animation is fixed, how could i do that?
here is my animation

```
 #me{
    background-image: url("walkingirl.png");
    width: 200px;
    height: 509px;
    top: -151px;
    left: 180px;
    position: fixed;
   animation: play 2s steps(10) infinite;
  }

@keyframes play {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: -2000px 0; }
}
```

Comment: Can not be achieved only with CSS - you need JavaScript to handle `scroll` events and trigger your animation.

Comment: My JavaScript skills are not the best, is it something with  $(window).scroll(function() {} ?

Comment: Exactly. Move the `animation` CSS declartion to a different class, when scroll starts add the class to `#me`. If you want the animation to stop when scrolling stops it gets more complicated - you need to debounce your JS execution.

Comment: Thanks, that works great, now i just need to figure out how to stop it and start it again:))